# Duplicates in SPARQL clause VALUES lead to unexplainable result

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I accidentaly noticed that if you write SPARQL query like [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fid%20%3FidLabel%20WHERE%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fid%20%7B%20wd%3AQ1%20%20wd%3AQ1%20%20%7D.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

```
SELECT ?id ?idLabel WHERE{
  VALUES ?id { wd:Q1  wd:Q1  }.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

the result is kinda strange: four rows instead of expected two.

I get it that it's lame to write duplicates in the `VALUE` clause, but I'm just wondering why it works like this. Could someone explain please?

Comment: bug or some odd behaviour with the label service I'd say - this is non standard SPARQL, so just ignore it in your corner case with duplicates in VALUES

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of the non standard label service. When running this query you get two results for the wikibase:label of wd:Q1, these are then added to each wd:Q1. So when you have 2 same values you will get 4 rows, if you have 3 same values, you'll get 9 and so on.